# Android App using sql server database on a local PC with valid IP?

Tags: android, ip, localhost

I am new to Android and I want to develop an app with B4a .. We have a local web application and an android app which should connect to local sql .. If the local sql server has a valid IP .. is there any way that I can connect to this database from android app over internet ? .. If not please help me how to do it..

Comment: Don't know about direct communication between and android app and Database server. But you can create a web application and provide the API for communication between Database server and android app.

Comment: can I use a webservice too?

Comment: yeah you can use it. I am using RESTful API using codeignitor as it is good enough for my need. You can use whichever suits you the best.